# Producing seperate text files from a large Json file

Tags: python, json, text

I'm trying to use the code below to produce a set of .txt files from a large .json file where there is one Json object per line, with date and a string of text. I want the date to be the filename.

When I open up the .json file (in sublime text editor), it shows me 2272 lines, so I assume the code should produce this number of text files. However, it is only producing half as many. Can anybody tell me why, and what I should do to correct this?

[image]

```
import json

#with open('results.json') as json_file:
data = [json.loads(line) for line in open('results.json', 'r')]
for p in data:
    date = p["date"]
    filename = date.replace(" ", "_").replace(":","_")
    print(filename)
    text = p["text"]
    with open('Articles2/'+filename+'.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(text+'\n')
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you add an example of your json?

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: unrelated code improvement suggestion: use `()` rather than `[]` in your `data = ...` line. This will prevent your application from reading the whole file into memory all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have duplicate dates in your sample data, so each iteration of your `for` loop is creating a new entry and then overwriting the entries where the date is the exact same.

For example: `2018-11-17 17:11:48` with 3 entries about 13 lines down in your data. This will only create 1 new file because your new file creation criteria in your script is only based on the `date` data.

You need to add some other unique value to the date to make them unique so `open()` doesn't overwrite the file that already exists. ie. add milliseconds to your date, concat values from the "text" property in your JSON object, add a counter, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't spot that. I'm going to try to add a source url column to the data so I can figure out why I'm getting duplicate dates, it may be that there's more than one article per date / time, or that several urls point produce the same article.